# Python object as a list of lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, deap

I'm trying to develop a class that behaves as a list of lists. I need it to pass it as a type for an individual, in deap framework. Presently, I'm working with numpy object array. Here is the code.

```
import numpy

class MyArray(numpy.ndarray):
    def __init__(self, dim):
        numpy.ndarray.__init__(dim, dtype=object)
```

But when I try to pass values to the object of `MyArray`,

```
a = MyArray((2, 2))
a[0][0] = {'procID': 5}
```

I get an error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/PythonProjects/NSGA/src/test.py", line 23, in <module>
    'procID': 5
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'
```

Any suggestions are welcome. You can also show me a different way without making use of numpy which facilitates type creation.

A similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732330/python-class-that-works-as-list-of-lists)

Comment: Perhaps you should try `pandas` for converting dict to an numpy array equivalent.

Comment: You can look into one of the ways mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535374/initialize-a-numpy-array) and modify the initialization part according to your own logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html), it looks like `ndarray` uses `__new__()` to do its initialization, not `__init__()`. In particular, the `dtype` of the array is already set before your `__init__()` method runs, which makes sense because `ndarray` needs to know what its `dtype` is to know how much memory to allocate. (Memory allocation is associated with `__new__()`, not `__init__()`.) So you'll need to override `__new__()` to provide the `dtype` parameter to `ndarray`.

```
class MyArray(numpy.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, dim):
        return numpy.ndarray.__new__(cls, dim, dtype=object)
```

Of course, you can *also* have an `__init__()` method in your class. It will run after `__new__()` has finished, and that would be the appropriate place to set additional attributes or anything else you may want to do that doesn't have to modify the behavior of the `ndarray` constructor.

Incidentally, if the only reason you're subclassing `ndarray` is so that you can pass `dtype=object` to the constructor, I'd just use a factory function instead. But I'm assuming there's more to it in your real code.